# sqlite: how to enable foreign keys in ios (PRAGMA foreign_keys always returns 0)

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

IOS, SQLite Implementation Question

Despite attempting to turn foreign keys on immediately after establishing a connection, and even though the result of that query does not produce an error, my subsequent check reveals that foreign keys are not enabled.

I can't figure out why. Here is the code:

```
    var sqliteDB: COpaquePointer = nil
    let dbPath = (documentsPath as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("test.sqlite3")

    let status = sqlite3_open(dbPath.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, &sqliteDB)
    if status != SQLITE_OK {
        print("Error Opening Database")
        if let errMsg = String.fromCString(sqlite3_errmsg(sqliteDB)) {
            print("\(errMsg)")
        }
    }

    if sqlite3_exec(sqliteDB, "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        let err = String.fromCString(sqlite3_errmsg(sqliteDB))
        print("error attempting to enable foreign keys: \(err)")
    }

    let test = sqlite3_exec(sqliteDB, "PRAGMA foreign_keys", nil, nil, nil)

    print("Result of check: \(test)")   // Result of check: 0
```

In the above code 'test' is always zero, indicating that foreign keys are not enabled. I have also tried using sqlite3_prepare_v2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you test for "PRAGMA foreign_keys", you need to load an actual row, the row that contains the boolean you are looking for. sqlite3_exec is not the correct way to load a row: it is dedicated to easily execute a bunch of SQL statements, not to load rows.

Here is how to check:

```swift
var statement: COpaquePointer = nil
if sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqliteDB, "PRAGMA foreign_keys", -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
    let err = String.fromCString(sqlite3_errmsg(sqliteDB))
    print("error building statement: \(err)")
}
if sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_ROW {
    print("expected a row")
}
let foreignKeysEnabled = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0) != 0
sqlite3_finalize(statement)
print("enabled: \(foreignKeysEnabled)")
```

BTW, you can also use a ready-made SQLite wrapper such as https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift

Comment: Thanks! This works.... But why do you need to load an actual row.. and do you have a link to where this information is found? Your SQLite library looks pretty good as well, thank you. I'm currently just learning about how sqlite works in ios/swift.

Comment: "But why do you need to load an actual row?" Well, because the statement `PRAGMA foreign_keys` returns its result in a row.

Comment: "do you have a link to where this information is found?" Not really, but now you know how to query SQLite with pragma statements: https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html

Comment: With GRDB, loading the first boolean returned by `PRAGMA foreign_keys` is as simple as `Bool.fetchOne(db, "PRAGMA foreign_keys")` (load the boolean found in the leftmost column of the first row returned by the SQL statement). For example: https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/v0.43.1/GRDB/Migrations/Migration.swift#L8

Comment: And if this answer is OK for you, you can check it as "accepted" :-)